# javascript redirects doesn't open in same tab?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have been creating a webpage for the last few days and the concept in this webpage is that the user enters a custom text in a `textarea`.
Then the value of that `textarea` will be treated with javascript.
`if(x=="hello")` ,then javascript will have to redirect the user to another webpage but in the same tab and in the same window. 
Unfortunately this is not working. I mean javascript redirect the webpage to another url but it's not in the same tab.

PLEASE CAN ANYBODY HELP ME TO FIX MY ERROR?

Note:Please do not give me answers with jQuery because I don't know how to use it

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripting1.js"></script>
      <style type"text/css">
             .inputtext
             {
             border:5px double #4f2d05;
             width:1378px;
             height:690px;
             background-color:#000000;
             font-family:monospace;
             font-size:28px;
             color:#00ff00;
             resize:none;
             }
             textarea:focus{outline: 0}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body background="camouflage.jpg">
      <table name="table" align="center">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <img src="header.png" />
            </td>
         </tr>

         <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr>
         </tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
         <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr>
         </tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
         <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
         <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>

         <form name="form1">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div align="center">
                     <textarea 
                        class="inputtext" 
                        id="myTextarea" 
                        name="text1" 
                        align="center" 
                        placeholder="Enter command here....">
                     </textarea>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input 
                     type="submit" 
                     name="submit" 
                     OnSubmit="myFunction();"
                     >
               </td>
            </tr>
         </form>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE (external .js file and html is linking to it)**

```
function myFunction(){
   var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
   if (x == "hello"){
      window.open('http://google.com/'
   }, '_self);
   }

   else{alert('ok i knew it'); }
}
```

Comment: I assume it's a typo, but you've got an unclosed string with your `'_self` argument to `window.open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect code is wrong, try this:

**`Edit`**

Here is the code broken up into separate files.  In order to have it run, just put all the files into the root of your site directory.  If you move them around or change their names, be sure to change their location in the `.html` file.

Do note, just because you move the JavaScript to a separate `.js` file, does not mean that the "`hello`" is hidden from the user.  It just means that they will have to navigate to the separate `js` page to find it.  In order to truly hide it, you'd have to send the user input to a server, validate it, and send a validation response.

**redirector.js**

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
   if (x === "hello") {
      document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
      return false;
   }
   else {
      alert('ok i knew it');
      return false;
   }
}
```

**index.css**

```
#container{
   text-align: center;
}
.inputtext{
   border: 5px double #4f2d05;
   width: 1378px;
   height: 690px;
   background-color: #000000;
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 28px;
   color: #00ff00;
   resize: none;
}
textarea:focus{
   outline: 0
}
```

**indexl.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Terminal</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
      <script src="redirector.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <form name="form1" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
            <div>
               <textarea 
                  class="inputtext" 
                  id="myTextarea" 
                  name="text1" 
                  placeholder="Enter command here...."></textarea>
            </div>
            <input 
               type="submit" 
               name="submit">
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zero298, this solved the redirection issue.
but can you tell me how to make the script external please?
I don't want the (if x === "hello") to be visible in the source of the webpage. thanks again

Comment: @user3032871 Sure, check my edits.  Do note, moving the `(if x === "hello")` to a separate file really doesn't hide it from the user.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. You helped me a lot! Thanks for your time, and for the code you gave me :)

Comment: @user3032871 No problem. Let me know if there are any other problems.  Don't forget to upvote if it was helpful and accept if it solved your problem.

Comment: In fact, I have a new issue :$ I have posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201891/how-to-fix-autofocus-issue-in-html

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
window.open('http://google.com/','_self);
```

try

```
location.href = "http://google.com/";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.location.href` instead. `window.open` opens another window

`window.location.href ='http://google.com/'`

Comment: `location.href` is not a method/function, but a property. You should assign a new value instead of calling it.

Comment: I know. I was going to suggest window.location.replace() at first.